# Secure and legitimate way to get remote access to another Android phone (without root)

Tags: remote-control, remote-access

Let's say that I have a legitimate reason and permission of someone to do something akin to screen-mirroring (a'la VNC, desktop sharing of PCs) through remote login of their Android phone, over the network on my PC or my Android phone, without requiring phone to be rooted, in a very secure manner s.t. others or malafide crooks cannot use same method for nefarious reasons. Is there some such solution available that someone could share pointers to with the above requirements ? It'd be also very desirable that I do not have to involve a third-party server (s.a. to avoid any potential man-in-the-middle security issues).

Please note that the use-case is legitimate because it is set up with the express knowledge and permission of the owner of the target Android handset and it is not for eavesdropping or other illegal purposes.

As for mechanism being secure, I'd hope that it'd be based on some strong security mechanisms s.a. preshared secrets, or preshared certificates for mutual authentication and ideally multi-factor.

When the device is being remote-controlled, on the target device there should be a very clear visual indication of such being underway.

Comment: The only solution which comes to my mind that doe snot use 3rd party servers is scrcpy in combination with ADB over Wifi/IP. The only problem is that ADB over IP is everything but secure as it is a plaintext protocol without any protection. All the other solutions base on a 3rd party app that has a system app signature and thus can share your screen.